# Stop NSTimer in a UICollectionViewCell after leaving view

Tags: ios, swift, nstimer, uicollectionviewcell

I have a `NSTimer` set up in a `UICollectionViewCell`. It's running ok, except it keeps on going even after i change the view through a segue. How should i stop it? One solution that came in mind is `NSNotificationCenter`. Is there a better way? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

How about creating a method for invalidate a timer for your cell and in `viewWillDisappear()`

call that method for all visible cells

```
let cells = self.tableView.visibleCells();
for cell in cells {
    // call invalidate
}
```

Comment: This is a good idea too. But i think that the timer doesn't stop on hidden cells...It doesn't even stop if i switch to another controller.

Comment: normally you should invalidate the previous timer in prepareForReuse() of your cell and do some logic to save the current running time of each cell (like timestamp) then continue the timer when it is showing again from (the save time + time elapse from save timestamp) (when you scroll back)

Comment: I'm invalidating the timers in the `viewWillDisappear` method and it works great.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure but when you give your timer a name, for example: `let myTimer:NSTimer = ...` then you can do in the `prepareForSegue` function: `myTimer.invalidate()` This function stops the timer.
So put all timers in an `var myArray = [NSTimer]()` and then in prepareForSegue:

```
for timer in myArray {
timer.invalidate()
}
```

Comment: I create a timer for each `UICollectionViewCell` so it's in the attached class. Is this wrong?

Comment: So what is the timer for? But you can also put all the timers in an Array and then stop all them within a for-Loop. I'll update my answer for you

Comment: It's for repeating an animation and doing some calculations. These calculations are specific to the cell. So each one should have a timer. I might try to use a single timer in the Controller and invalidating it in `viewWillDisappear` or try your version of invalidating. Thanks!

Comment: Also, the timer is created in the attached cell class. Shouldn't it be destroyed once the controller is changed?

Comment: I would rather program the selector of the timer in this way so that you only need to have one timer and then perform an action in the selector which cell was selected before. And I'm quite sure that the GarbageCollector removes the timer after some time so you shouldn't worry about that.

Comment: I was thinking about this, but i tested it with 30 cells and it works ok. I need it to perform actions in every visible cell, but this is a good solution thanks! I'm using @sizer solution at the moment, but i'll change it if it becomes laggy. Using one single timer is much more efficient, but the cells should be independent from each other.

Comment: Maybe you could initiate a variable, for example an Int value. In the didSelectItemAtIndex function you could set the variable depending on the index of the cell. Then you could perform an action in the timer's selector depending on the variable. (Best you do a switch-case function there)

Comment: At the time being, the timer starts for every cell when it's created. And it works in parallel for every cell. This is the way it should work. When i tap a cell, it should go to a detail page and stop all the timers. I thought that the timers would automatically stop, once the cells aren't visible any more, but i guess i was wrong.

Comment: Well you just have to do timer.invalidate() when the selector is finished. For example you could do a void function in which you do the code that I wrote in my answer above and then call the function at the end of every timer's selector. If you want to use such a big amount of timers...